# depthimage_to_laserscan vs pointcloud_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Could someone describe main differences, cons/pros between these 2 nodes? As I understand, pointcloud_to_laserscan uses PCL library and depthimage_to_laserscan using raw depth image.
Maybe someone of you performed some tests between them (who is better for ARM, RAM consumption, etc.)?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251495/depthimage_to_laserscan-vs-pointcloud_to_laserscan/) by [Robotics_weekends](https://answers.ros.org/users/27920/robotics_weekends/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the wiki, http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan it depends on the raw data:

"If you're trying to create a virtual laserscan from your RGBD device, and your sensor is forward-facing, you'll find depthimage_to_laserscan will be much more straightforward and efficient since it operates on image data instead of bulky pointclouds. However, if your sensor is angled, or you have some other esoteric use case, you may find this node to be very helpful!"

---

Originally posted by [sheldonr](https://answers.ros.org/users/37896/sheldonr/) with karma: 36 on 2018-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2